# How to use :hover on two of the same elements

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with CSS animations and I've made a navbar where the  tags have an outline and a wave effect is made by animating another  tag with a clip-path polygon. I am currently trying to make it so, on hover, the inner  element's height increase to completely fill the outline. But I don't know how to use :hover with two elements of the same tag. I tried .nthChild but it didn't seem to work. It could be my transition though. Also, run snippet in fullscreen as I haven't made it responsive. Thanks :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
}

nav {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 8vh;
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
}

.logo h2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.logo h2:nth-child(1)
{
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #03a9f4;
}
.logo h2:nth-child(2)
{
  animation: animate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  color: #03a9f4;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 45%, 15% 44%, 32% 50%, 54% 60%, 70% 61%, 84% 59%, 100% 52%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  50%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 60%, 16% 65%, 34% 66%, 51% 62%, 67% 50%, 84% 45%, 100% 46%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%
}

.nav-links li{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: height 4s;
}

.nav-links a:nth-child(1) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #03a9f4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-links a:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  color: #03a9f4;
  overflow: hidden;

}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 45%, 15% 44%, 32% 50%, 54% 60%, 70% 61%, 84% 59%, 100% 52%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  50%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 60%, 16% 65%, 34% 66%, 51% 62%, 67% 50%, 84% 45%, 100% 46%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Liquid</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Nav</h2>
      <h2>Nav</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
         <a id='outline' href="./index.html"><h3>Home</h3></a>
          <a id='wave' href="./index.html"><h3>Home</h3></a>
       </li>
       
      <li>
        <a id='outline' href="./contact.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a>
        <a id='wave'href="./contact.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a id='outline' href="./canvas.html"><h3>Visualizer</h3></a>
        <a id='wave'href="./canvas.html"><h3>Visualizer</h3></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

<main></main>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you check your CSS as you have, for example, two declarations for keyframes animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will need two selectors:

- `.nav-links a:nth-child(1):hover + a`
- `.nav-links a:nth-child(2):hover`

You can combine them with a comma, like this:

```
.nav-links a:nth-child(1):hover + a,
.nav-links a:nth-child(2):hover {
  animation: none;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
}

nav {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  min-height: 8vh;
}

.logo{
  position: relative;
}

.logo h2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.logo h2:nth-child(1)
{
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #03a9f4;
}
.logo h2:nth-child(2)
{
  animation: animate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  color: #03a9f4;
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%
}

.nav-links li{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: height 4s;
}

.nav-links a:nth-child(1) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #03a9f4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-links a:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  color: #03a9f4;
  overflow: hidden;

}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 45%, 15% 44%, 32% 50%, 54% 60%, 70% 61%, 84% 59%, 100% 52%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  50%
  {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 60%, 16% 65%, 34% 66%, 51% 62%, 67% 50%, 84% 45%, 100% 46%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
}

.nav-links a:nth-child(1):hover + a,
.nav-links a:nth-child(2):hover {
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Liquid</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <h2>Nav</h2>
      <h2>Nav</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
         <a id='outline' href="./index.html"><h3>Home</h3></a>
          <a id='wave' href="./index.html"><h3>Home</h3></a>
       </li>
       
      <li>
        <a id='outline' href="./contact.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a>
        <a id='wave'href="./contact.html"><h3>Contact</h3></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a id='outline' href="./canvas.html"><h3>Visualizer</h3></a>
        <a id='wave'href="./canvas.html"><h3>Visualizer</h3></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

<main></main>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the animation running and gradually fill the text?

Comment: Yes. Instead of `animation: none` add a _new animation_ which fills the text up to the top. Then, when you hover over the text, the CSS will just swap the old animation for the new animation. You can even use comma-separation to apply multiple animations to the same element - so you could keep the old animation going and apply the new animation at the same time.